# Symfony2 JMSDiExtraBundle child service dependency error

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, symfony-2.1

I'm using JMSDiExtraBundle in my Symfony2 project.

Here is my the problem:

**Repository.php**

```
abstract class Repository extends DocumentRepository implements ReadOnlyRepositoryInterface {
    protected $dm;
    protected $repo;
    protected $query;

   /**
    * @InjectParams({
    *       "dm" = @Inject("doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager")
    * })
    */
    public function __construct(DocumentManager $dm) {
        $this->dm = $dm;

        parent::__construct($dm, $this->dm->getUnitOfWork(), new ClassMetadata($this->getDocumentName()));

        $this->query = $this->dm->createQueryBuilder($this->getDocumentName());
    }
}
```

**PostRepository.php**

```
/**
 * @Service("post_repository")
 */
class PostRepository extends Repository implements PostRepositoryInterface {
    private $uploader;

    /**
     * @InjectParams({
     *      "dm" = @Inject("doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager"),
     *      "uploader" = @Inject("uploader"),
     * })
     */
    public function __construct(DocumentManager $dm, UploaderService $uploader) {
        parent::__construct($dm);

        $this->uploader = $uploader;
    }
}
```

As can be seen, PostRepository requires 2 dependency : DocumentManager (later injected to Repository as parent) and Uploader.

But it seems that Symfony does something which making it assumed that PostRepository needed 3 dependency : DocumentManager, DocumentManager (again) and Uploader, which off course gives an error since I explicitly stated that the second parameter is required to be an Uploader instance.

Here's from `appDevDebugProjectContainer.xml` :

```
<service id="post_repository" class="BusinessLounge\BlogBundle\Repository\PostRepository">
  <argument type="service" id="doctrine_mongodb.odm.default_document_manager"/>
  <argument type="service" id="doctrine_mongodb.odm.default_document_manager"/>
  <argument type="service" id="uploader"/>
</service>
```

and `appDevDebugProjectContainer.php` :

```
/**
 * Gets the 'post_repository' service.
 *
 * This service is shared.
 * This method always returns the same instance of the service.
 *
 * @return BusinessLounge\BlogBundle\Repository\PostRepository A BusinessLounge\BlogBundle\Repository\PostRepository instance.
 */
 protected function getPostRepositoryService()
 {
    $a = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb.odm.default_document_manager');

    return $this->services['post_repository'] = new \BusinessLounge\BlogBundle\Repository\PostRepository($a, $a, $this->get('uploader'));
}
```

Is this an intended behavior? Or a bug perhaps? Or I did something wrong?

Need advice!

Comment: Why are you adding the inject in the abstract class? Just remove the @InjectParams part in your abstract parent class, since it is abstract you cant instantiate it anyways.

Comment: It looks like a bug, maybe you should report it?

Comment: @m0c that is a very good point, though it doesn't really resolve my curiosity about the behavior. But your answer saved the day :)

Comment: @MatthieuNapoli it does seems like a bug, but then again I did googled and no one seems to complain about it so it could be my code that's breaking the convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just remove the @InjectParams on your abstract parent class, since it is never instantiated anyways. Then only the things you need are injected in your real service.